# Use 32 bit or 64 bit for eclipse for development

Tags: eclipse

I am new for java and deployment too. I have a few questions about using Eclipse. My machine is Windows 7 with 64 bit. If I export my project into runnable jar file, would the application  run on Windows XP 32 bit machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java bytecode is platform-independent. The 64-bit vs 32-bit is just the architecture of the JVM.

So yes, you should be able to run on Windows XP 32-bit as long as it has the required version of Java installed.

Also, whether you use Eclipse or not also makes no difference. It is simply an IDE, not a compiler.

Comment: Just for additional clarity..* 64-bit vs 32 bit is just the architecture of the JVM that eclipse will run in.